# How to add back linear model to time series

Tags: time-series, linear-model, prediction

I have data for a time series made stationary by subtracting a linear model Xt=2.1+1.2t. Now I have to make predictions for the next 4 observations on the original scale. How do I add back the line to get the original series data in r?

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract a trend, then you work with an additive model.

Suppose you have a series of residuals after subtracting the LM: Xres == Xt - Xlm. You proceed with modeling Xres as you wish, for example take an auto-regression component, to get Xar.

When the time to make a final prediction has come, you just take Xar, make predictions 4 steps ahead, and add Xlm to it with supplying 4 time indexes into the lm model; you end up with Xpred == Xar + Xlm. So you do the additive part.